# TAP FOR FIREWALL

Tags: linux, networking

I need some guidance. I'm really not sure what it is called.

I'd like to set up a firewall or tap between my router (Ubiquiti Edge) and our network.
I know I can monitor network traffic with our router but I'd like to experiment with setting up a firewall or tap to monitor all network traffic between the router and my network.

```
<ROUTER TO PUBLIC IP>---<FIREWALL OR TAP WITH 2 NICS>--<LAN 192.168.1.0/24>
```

I have a Centos8 box with two nics and I'd like all network traffic to go through this device.
It ip a:
eno1: . . .
  inet 192.168.1.10/24
enp4s0: 
  inet 192.168.1.11/24

I have never done anything like this.
I'm not even sure what it is called.

Thanks

Please throw me a bone.

Comment: Does the router not provide a firewall setting? I have an EdgeRouter X and an EdgeRouter Lite, and both allows me to enable a firewall.

Comment: Yes my edge router has a firewall.   I just want to add a device between the edge router and my network for testing to use in another network where I have a gateway with no firewall or filter.  I just is a bit easier to add a device and track ip addresses.  In other words we want to catch people trying to bypass the router.  It is also somewhat of a honeypot.